# Selenium Python queston: How to extract the dynamic id generated?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I have a link inside a table with a dynamically changing id, the xpath being:
`//*[@id="1544727471470-1-uiGrid-0007-cell"]/a/span/span`

To its left is a checkbox with xpath:
`//*[@id="1544727471470-1-uiGrid-0007-cell"]/input`

As I go down the table, the string after the dynamic id ('1') gets implemented, and so the fifth row would have the xpath:
`//*[@id="1544727471470-`**5**`-uiGrid-0007-cell"]/a/span/span`

I can infer that the checkbox next to it will be:
`//*[@id="1544727471470-`**5**`-uiGrid-0007-cell"]`**/input**

So, you see the pattern.
What I need to do is capture the dynamic id `("1544727471470")`, and from there, I can write logic to create my xpaths and target any row in view and click on its checkbox.

I tried looking at page source, but shows nothing about the dynamic ids.

Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use the `contains()` xpath function or the `*=`, `^=`, `$=` family of CSS selectors to look up the desired element with the partial match on the `id` attribute and then extract the id attribute to get the dynamically changing part.

Something along these lines:

```
element_with_the_dynamic_id = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[id$="uiGrid-0007-cell"]')
dynamic_id = element_with_the_dynamic_id.get_attribute("id")

dynamic_part = dynamic_id.split("-", 1)[0]
print(dynamic_part)
```

`$=` here means "ends with"; `.split("-", 1)` splits by the first occurence of `-`.

---

If you prefer XPaths, you could use `contains()` (`ends-with()` unfortunately is XPath 2.0 only):

```
element_with_the_dynamic_id = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "uiGrid-0007-cell")]')
```

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly!  The get_attribute was the key step for me.  Thank  you very much!